# please how to submit data from a table with reactJS

Tags: reactjs

```
const [InputFields,setInputFields] = useState([{title:""}]);

const handleChangeInput=(index,event)=>{
    const values = [...InputFields];
    values[index][event.target.name]  = event.target.value;
    setInputFields(values);
}
const handleAddField=()=>{
    setInputFields([...InputFields,{title:""}])
}

const [course,setCourse] = useState([]);
 const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(InputFields)
    // create prerequis
     {InputFields.map(i=>{
        axios.post("api/",i)
     })}   
}
```

here is what I did just that it duplicates the data in DB please does anyone have a better way to do this

Comment: You've shared the code from your javascript but not the code on the server which I guess inserts the data to the DB, please share that as well

Comment: yes the insertion of the data is not a problem, I just need to know how I can insert an array of data through axios with the code I published it inserts but it duplicates the data on insertion

Comment: Simply sending the data in the second parameter of the function, like so: 
`axios.post('api/', {data: InputFields})`
Also, check out the [docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example) of axios about post request